# Get Back "Yesterday" on Sidebar in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, search, finder, sidebar

I deleted my yesterday option in my sidebar by mistake and am wondering if there is some way to get it back.

Comment: By the way, if EvilChookie's answer solved the problem, remember to mark it as "accepted"!

Comment: I've been so paranoid of accidentally deleting those items ... I feel much less paranoid now knowing that there is such an easy cure :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Finder's Preferences, click `Sidebar` and tick the appropriate entries under `Search For` and bam!

[image]